# Behaviour of Scala ReduceLeft

Tags: scala, reduce

In the following code snippet I'm using reduceLeft and foreach loop to find the sum of the differences of a number against all of the list members. I was expecting that the result from these two would be the same (1050) but reduceLeft is adding extra 50 (val x) in final answer. What is the reason behind that?

```
  val list = List(200,400,600)
  val x = 50
  println(list.reduceLeft((total, cur) => total + Math.abs(x - cur)))

  var total = 0l
  list.foreach(p => {
    total = total + Math.abs(x - p)
  })

  println(total)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are not subtracting 50 from the first value in the list. Your reduceLeft function is doing this:

```
Iteration 1: 200 + Math.abs(50 - 400)
Iteration 2: 550 + Math.abs(50 - 600)
Result: 1100
```

Try using foldLeft

```
list.foldLeft(0)((total, cur) => total + Math.abs(50 - cur))
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification, It makes more sense to use foldLeft here.

Answer (score 2):

I think `foldLeft` gives better clarity, but you can still use `reduceLeft` by prepending the list with a `0` to serve as the initial value:

```
(0 :: list).reduceLeft((total, cur) => total + Math.abs(x - cur))
```